# Permission denied (publickey) - Cant push or pull with Git

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, git-bash, ssh-keygen

Git was working fine with pushing to Bitbucket, until recently where there haven't been much changes, except for a change in DNS server settings.

**The error:**

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I used keygen to create a new key, add the key with Git Bash (key was added and accepted) and then manually add the key to Bitbucket SSH. However, it's still yielding the same error.

Not sure what went wrong, does anyone have the same experience and able to help?

**Other bits of info or attempts to troubleshoot**

- `git remote -v`, one push, one pull item listed
- `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` - error: Permission denied (publickey).
- `ssh-add -l` - error: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
- `ssh -vT git@github.com` - error below

> ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

```
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c /* rest of numbers */
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

- `ssh-agent -s`, error:

> ```
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-2KEE1p8SGXPg/agent.1900; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
> SSH_AGENT_PID=2712; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
> echo Agent pid 2712;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the precise detailed question! Does the output of `ssh-add -L` match the entry on bitbucket?

Comment: DNS change? What kind of? Does `host -t a github.com` resolve to 192.30.252.129?

Comment: Wait a moment. Are you using bitbucket or github? Adding a key to bitbucket and expecting github to know about it would be a little bit optimistic. ;)

Comment: I changed my dns to the google servers to test some stuff. I also added keys to bitbucket....not github...@michas, cant see if match due to error msg. Im using bitbucket...i think host is github given the error above... Im not sure if its mixed up now... But i rarely ever push/pull to github with this machine

Comment: @michas when i type `ssh-add -L` error says `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`. @iltempo whats the exact command line? host ... doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer may not be the best of answers but I managed to get it working with the following steps. (Disclaimer: I still dont know what went wrong)

1. Kill all ssh-agent process by `kill PIDnumber` one by one within Git Bash. Somehow I had a list full of agent processes running. I saw this list of PID when I tried to uninstall Git from my system.
2. Uninstall Git from the computer
3. Remove all SSH keys from Bitbucket repo - (manually remove by browsing to BB website)
4. Reinstall Git and in Git bash, `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` + entered passphrase so user is login and confirmed
5. Added existing rsa_pub keys (i just dragged rsa_pub file to sublime text, copied the key and pasted it back to bitbucket in the same repo)
6. pull then push from nodejs's command line utility

Answer (score 2):

The message "Could not open a connection to your authentication" implies that no agent is running (or at least not reachable).

```
ssh-agent bash        # start a new agent
ssh-add               # add your key
ssh-add -L            # verify that your key is the same as on the server

ssh git@bitbucket.org             # should work now 
git clone git@bitbucket.org:xyz   # (or something like this) should work, too
```

Comment: sorry its github earlier bcos i posted the wrong command. I edited the corrected output which is still similar. When I start new agent, then add key ...same error of could not open connection to authentication agent.

Comment: When i type the above in Git Bash...I enter Passphrase and its accepted. But it says `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`. logged in as user but then says `u can use git or hg to connect to bitbucket, shell access is disabled. connection to bitbucket.org is closed.`

Comment: That's perfectly fine. you cannot open an interactive shell session on bitbucket. It allows only git (or hg) clients. The point is, you were able to connect and bitbucket answered.

Comment: The agent will start a new bash. only inside that bash the agent is available. Since you are using windows, maybe you want to use pagent, from the putty suite instead. (BTW: the output from `ssh-agent -s` in you question is **not** an error, those are exactly the connection informations used to set up that missing connection.)

Comment: Your question implied that you are using some kind of agent. Either `ssh-agent` or `pagent` are well known. It's not mandatory to use an agent, but it makes live a lot easier.

Comment: ok i tried pageant ...added keys. but when i pushed or pulled...still same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `ssh-agent` command and then export the variables that are displayed when you run it. To do that you can do something like this :

```
eval `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`
```

The output of the `ssh-agent` command is a valid shell script which when executed (a.k.a evaled) will set the right env variables required for the communication between `ssh-agent` program and other programs that use it.

Just make sure you kill your existing `ssh-agent` process before you run this command.

After that use the usual `ssh-add` commands to list and add keys and then your `ssh` should work just fine.

Comment: im assuming u mean run commands in git bash right? cos it doesnt work in nodejs. When i kill agent it says `ssh_agent_PID not set, cannot kill agent.` When i type eval...full line,  it gives a different agent PID from `ssh-agent`. Going back to node...i still cant git push or pull! Sorry!

Comment: @Thinkerer Yes, this has to be run in a bash like shell. I do not understand what you are referring to as `node` or `nodejs` here. Does node provide a shell of its own? If so then there are two things : 1) I do not know if the nodejs provided shell behaves like bash 2) You cannot run this command in one shell and have the same work in another shell. The eval command sets the env variables and they are process specific. To kill the agent, kill the process named ssh-agent with its pid. Btw, why do you want to run git commands from node shell and not git shell?

Comment: yes node provides a command line utility which I usually do my git pulls and pushes and it has been working fine till now. Im new to using node so the mix of node and git bash is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. after you generate a new SSH key (ssh-keygen -t rsa)
2. and add it to the bitbucket site (cat ~/.ssh/bitbucket.pub ...)
3. if you still not able to connect then do this:

   1. eval `ssh-agent -s`
   2. ssh-add bitbucket
   3. try again now again